# C# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dog' to 'Rottweiler

Tags: c#, casting

I was trying the following code from a book when the error occured. I am geussing it is generated because of wrong use of as keyword. Please, help me fix this error. This code is an example for subclassing. This code generates two errors (cs0266). The error generating lines are in the Main method and are marked with a comment above the line.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dog' to 'Rottweiler
        Rottweiler butch = new Rottweiler("Butch") as Dog;

        // CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dog' to 'Spaniel
        Spaniel mac = new Spaniel("Mac", "yips") as Dog;

        butch.Bark();
        mac.Bark();
        butch.DoYourThing();
        mac.DoYourThing();
    }
}
class Dog
{
    protected string _name;
    protected string _sound;

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        _name = name; _sound = "barks";
    }

    public Dog(string name, string sound)
    {
        _name = name;
        _sound = sound;
    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} at you", _name, _sound);
    }

    public virtual void DoYourThing()
    {
    }
}

class Rottweiler : Dog
{
    public Rottweiler(string name) : base(name) { }
    public Rottweiler(string name, string sound) : base(name, sound) { }

    public override void DoYourThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} snarls at you, in a very menacing fashion!", _name);
    }
}
class Spaniel : Dog
{
    public Spaniel(string name) : base(name) { }
    public Spaniel(string name, string sound) : base(name, sound) { }

    public override void DoYourThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} drools all over you, then licks you into submission!", _name);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should always post the error message and not just the error code, to avoid people having to go look up what the error code means.

Comment: Your compiler shouldn't just give you an errorcode, it gives you something like `error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` Try to understand thes and you proably would have saved the time to ask this question.

Comment: Thank you for the warningFrom now on I will post the entire error message :) Also I am a beginner still after reading the answers I felt a little ashamed because it now fell as it is something I should have known. I will be more carefull in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here: `Rottweiler butch = new Rottweiler("Butch") as Dog;` you're creating instance of `Rottweiler` and casting it to the `Dog`.

Still ok for now, but then you're assigning instance of `Dog` to the variable of type `Rottweiler` - but this is impossible.

Since `Rottweiler` is inherited from `Dog`, every `Rottweiler` is `Dog`, but not every `Dog` is `Rottweiler` - thus this implicit cast during assignment can't be done.

So either remove cast to `Dog`

```
Rottweiler butch = new Rottweiler("Butch");
```

or change type of `butch` to `Dog`:

```
Dog butch = new Rottweiler("Butch");
```

Notice in this case you also don't need explicit cast `... as Dog`, it will be done implicitly with assignment;

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick response :)

Answer (score 3):

While you can cast `Spaniel` to `Dog`, you can't do it the other way round. So this code:

```
Spaniel mac = new Spaniel("Mac", "yips") as Dog;
```

Is casting to `Dog` and then attempting to store that in a `Spaniel` variable. You can however do this:

```
Dog mac = new Spaniel("Mac", "yips") as Dog;
```

Also as mentioned by @leppie, the `as Dog` cast is not needed as there exists an implicit cast from a derived class to it's base:

```
Dog mac = new Spaniel("Mac", "yips");
```

Comment: `as Dog` ? That is redundant or might even be another error ;p

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick response :)